# extracting subtext between two characters using grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have text file which has information like follows

```
    @Mp_chzt_1
    asdjhsadhasdhdbjashdjaudashdjashdasdhasdhasdh
    asdasdkasjdkaskdskadkasdkasdkjaskldasdklasdas
    ahsjdasdfdfsdhghrtuztiuiuzozuoiouiouiouiouiou
    asjkjieqjeroiweoriksfjksjksjkf
    +
    !!!@!!!!!!!!++??????????????~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    BBBBBBBBBBBBMMMMMM!!!!!++LLLLLL******
    @Mp_btrea_1
    uokjjkzghqawsdasduihdlöklöaklöskdlkaökgzgzggz
    asdasduzuqwtzeqweuvixcvdjfiisduiifuzwpqüqwoeü
    kjkjiuijwiqquzwuziziqz
    +
    **********||||||||||||##@######++++?????????
    MMMMMMMMMUUUU***+++~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    @Mp_trwe_3
    jhtrqhkjiqkjkqwjelasjjljiewkjkljkldjflsjljki8u
    immhgwqtzopirpjgbsdkfjieipwippieoroeirkvsdjjfk
    jkahdjhjhfuhjkwekksjakjeiuwiurweiurioweuroweod
    poplrtm,ernmjhazqweqwjidiipfiopdifosidpfppsdif
    mnasnbdhgqweqweipoipoxkajksdökalsklsaksldkasöd
    asdas
    +
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!@@@@@???????????????????
```

I would like extract the region only between @Mp_* and + that comes right below the text and export it to txt file like following

```
    @Mp_chzt_1
    asdjhsadhasdhdbjashdjaudashdjashdasdhasdhasdh
    asdasdkasjdkaskdskadkasdkasdkjaskldasdklasdas
    ahsjdasdfdfsdhghrtuztiuiuzozuoiouiouiouiouiou
    asjkjieqjeroiweoriksfjksjksjkf
    @Mp_btrea_1
    uokjjkzghqawsdasduihdlöklöaklöskdlkaökgzgzggz
    asdasduzuqwtzeqweuvixcvdjfiisduiifuzwpqüqwoeü
    kjkjiuijwiqquzwuziziqz
    @Mp_trwe_3
    jhtrqhkjiqkjkqwjelasjjljiewkjkljkldjflsjljki8u
    immhgwqtzopirpjgbsdkfjieipwippieoroeirkvsdjjfk
    jkahdjhjhfuhjkwekksjakjeiuwiurweiurioweuroweod
    poplrtm,ernmjhazqweqwjidiipfiopdifosidpfppsdif
    mnasnbdhgqweqweipoipoxkajksdökalsklsaksldkasöd
    asdas
```

When I used the following code

```
grep -o -P '(?<=@MP.*).*(?=+)' query.txt > output.txt
```

It gave me "grep: nothing to repeat".
Could anyone guide where my mistake is and how to rectify it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fedorqui I forgot mention it earlier , now I have edited it. Kindly take a look. I want between @Mp.* and + symbol that comes below the text.

Comment: lines starting with @does not have fixed number of lines, it varies for every entry. I have edited the question. Kindly take a look

Comment: Sure. Now the picture is clear. I have posted an answer addressing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `awk` for this:

```
awk '/^@/{f=1} /^+/ {f=0} f' file > output.txt
```

Or, if you have leading spaces, match them with `\s*`:

```
awk '/^\s*@/{f=1} /^\s*\+/ {f=0} f' file > output.txt
```

This uses a flag `f` to decide whether the line should be printed or not.

- When it sees a line starting with `@`, it activates it.
- When it sees a line starting with `+`, it deactivates it.
- Then, it evaluates the flag and prints if it is True.

With your given input it returns:

```
@Mp_chzt_1
asdjhsadhasdhdbjashdjaudashdjashdasdhasdhasdh
asdasdkasjdkaskdskadkasdkasdkjaskldasdklasdas
ahsjdasdfdfsdhghrtuztiuiuzozuoiouiouiouiouiou
asjkjieqjeroiweoriksfjksjksjkf
@Mp_btrea_1
uokjjkzghqawsdasduihdlöklöaklöskdlkaökgzgzggz
asdasduzuqwtzeqweuvixcvdjfiisduiifuzwpqüqwoeü
kjkjiuijwiqquzwuziziqz
@Mp_trwe_3
jhtrqhkjiqkjkqwjelasjjljiewkjkljkldjflsjljki8u
immhgwqtzopirpjgbsdkfjieipwippieoroeirkvsdjjfk
jkahdjhjhfuhjkwekksjakjeiuwiurweiurioweuroweod
poplrtm,ernmjhazqweqwjidiipfiopdifosidpfppsdif
mnasnbdhgqweqweipoipoxkajksdökalsklsaksldkasöd
asdas
```

Comment: I tried your code but it just prints entire contents as it is. It didnt extract the specific part between @Mp and first + below the  text

Comment: Do you have leading spaces in the code? I assumed they are not there. If they are, use `awk '/^\s*@/{f=1} /^\s*+/ {f=0} f'` instead. See my update.

Comment: hi, your first code with f flag worked fine. But in spite of '@ ' is it possible to activate whenever it sees Mp and deactivates whenever it sees first + symbol below the text

Comment: @deena sure, just replace `/^\s*@/` for `/Mp/` (can match anywhere in the line, not only in the beginning of the line) and `/\+/`.

Comment: thank you very much. I would like learn these awk command..is there any tutorial you would specify?

Comment: @deena glad to help here. You can find good links in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info , I specially like the "idiomatic awk" one!